# How can I ensure that only the message I sent, and nothing else reaches the receiver?

Tags: tls, cryptography, hash, java, data-leakage

How do I make sure that the open channel I use to send a message to a specific receiver, is not used by a third party to send unwanted files and compromise the receivers system? Is there a method by which I could notice if any additional files or messages were transferred?

Comment: MD5 check sum? we dont even know what kind of technology you are using please be more specific

Comment: Are you not authenticating the sender?

Comment: Perhaps just digital signatures is enough. Look at PGP or even the new saltpack.org

Comment: Can you add more information to this question? By "open channel", do you mean existing connection, unencrypted connection, or both?

Answer (score 1):

Use TLS.

Create a TLS connection between you and the server and verify no MITM has occurred (check certs, fingerprints, etc).

No third party will be able to inject any payload as they will not be able to encrypt/decrypt within your TLS connection.

Comment: Don't forget to use `Client Authentication` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake).